# Identifying Duplicate Transactions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently because of an issue, multiple duplicate transactions were inserted into the database at different timings. Need to find those duplicate transactions and remove them.

I tried grouping the members and transactions

```
   select count(*),
          member_id,
          TRUNC(created, 'DDD') 
     from TXN
    where created > TO_DATE('06/01/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 group by member_id,
          TRUNC(created, 'DDD') 
   having count(*) > 2;
```

I need all the transactions that were created in 10 minutes of time difference for the same member.

**Examples:**

```
MEMBER_ID  ROW_ID  ORG  DEST  Created
1-FRGD     1-FGTH  YFG  DFG   10-01-2019 00:00:00:00
1-FRGD     1-TYHG  THU  SEF   10-01-2019 00:00:09:12
1-FGHR     1-FTGH  TGH  DRF   10-01-2019 00:01:03:25
```

In this example, I need the first two txns as output because of not more than 10minutes if time difference and has the same member number

Comment: What is the `TXN` *structure*, please? Which transactions are *duplicates* (are transactions duplicates if and only if they have the same `member_id`?) Could you provide some *examples* of the transactions (records in `TXN`)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko In Txn table I do have the only member_id to find duplicates.
One thing I can use is the Time when it got created like mostly not more than 10 minutes of time difference.

Comment: Can you give some sample input and output you want?

Comment: Provided the examples Thanks for giving your time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want *self join*:

```
  select a.Member_Id as Member_Id,
         a.Row_Id    as Row_Id, 
         a.Org       as Org,  
         a.Dest      as Dest ,
         a.Created   as Created,
         b.Row_Id    as Duplicate_Row_Id, 
         b.Org       as Duplicate_Org,  
         b.Dest      as Duplicate_Dest,
         b.Created   as Duplicate_Created 
    from TXN a inner join
         TXN b on a.Member_Id = b.Member_Id and 
                  a.Created < b.Created and
                  TIMESTAMPDIFF(a.Created, b.Created) / 60 <= 10
order by a.Member_Id
```

For each record in `TNX` you provide its duplicate(s).

Comment: With this one, I'm getting results having duplicate_ROW_ID and duplicate created..... and everything as null.

Comment: @Addala Shivateja: I'm sorry, it must be `inner join`, not `left` one: we don't want to get records with no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete these transactions:

```
delete tnext
    from txn tnext join
         txn t
         on tnext.member_id = t.member_id and
            tnext.created > t.created and
            tnext.created < t.created + interval 10 minute
   where t.created > '2019-06-01';
```

Be sure you backup the table and test the logic using `select` before running this on your actual table.

If you simply want to select transactions without the duplicates, I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from txn t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t tprev
                  where tprev.member_id = t.member_id and
                        tprev.created < t.created and
                        tprev.created > t.created - interval 10 minute
                 ) and
      t.created >= '2019-06-01';
```